# Missing string data when input stream has been reading

Tags: swift, sockets, swift3, inputstream

I try to receive data with inputStream.read method the message was missing some character. My messages is too long. example if my message is 30000 character, output string is 2000 character. 1000 character is missing.

```
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:bufferSize)
    var output:String = ""
    while(inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable){
        let bytesRead:Int = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        if bytesRead > 0 {
            var outputString:String=(NSString(bytes:buffer, length:bytesRead, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? String)!
            if(output != "" ){
                if(output.hasPrefix("ping")){  }else{
                    output = output + outputString
                }
            }else{
                    output=outputString
            }
        }else{
            print("# Error Reading")
            connect()
            login()
        }
        usleep(100000)
    }
```

Comment: Is the data you receive pure ASCII or does it contain non-ASCII characters? If it is the latter, you might split a UTF8 byte sequence which then can't be decoded properly by `String`. Also `hasBytesAvailable` doesn't block, it just says whether there is currently any data in the buffer. So maybe you just exit your loop too early.

Comment: thank you for answer.My mistake was two different thread use inputStream.read method